# Updating FormGroup in Angular - Uncaught Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with path

Tags: angular, forms

I have a table which displays a list of template names where each name has a FormControl requiring it to be non-empty. The FormControls are put in a FormGroup. There is also a button for sending an updated name to the API.

```
<form *ngIf="templateForm" [formGroup]="templateForm">
  <table class="table bg-white">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Template name</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let template of templates; trackBy: trackByFn">
      <td [formGroupName]="template.templateName">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="{{ 'templateName' + template.templateName }}"
          formControlName="templateName"
          [ngClass]="{
                  'form-control': true,
                  'is-invalid': templateForm.controls[template.templateName].get('templateName').invalid
                }"
          value="{{ template.templateName }}"
        />
        <p class="invalid-feedback">Required field</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn fhi-btn-secondary m-2" [disabled]="templateForm.controls[template.templateName].invalid" (click)="saveTemplateName(template)">
          {{ templateForm.controls[template.templateName].dirty ? 'Save' : 'Saved' }}
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Here is an extract of the `.ts`-file:

```
export class DimensionTemplatesComponent implements OnInit{
    templates: Template[];
    templateForm: FormGroup;

    private formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadTemplates();
    }

    private loadTemplates(): void {
    this.dataService.getTemplates().subscribe((data) => {
      this.templates = data;
      this.templateForm = this.buildTemplateForm(this.formBuilder, this.templates);
    });
    }

    private buildTemplateForm(formBuilder: FormBuilder, templates: Template[]) {
        const formControls = {};
        for (const template of templates) {
            formControls[template.templateName] = new FormGroup({
              templateName: new FormControl(template.templateName, [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]),
            });
        }
        return formBuilder.group(formControls);
    }

    saveTemplateName(template: Template) {
      const newTemplateName = this.templateForm.get(template.templateName).get('templateName').value;
      this.dataService.putTemplateName(template.templateName, newTemplateName).subscribe(() => {
        this.loadDimensionTemplates();
      });
    }
}
```

The form works fine when the page is refreshed and nothing is changed, but if I update a template name, click save, then try to edit that name again, I will get an error saying `Uncaught Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with path: 'template2 -> templateName'` (if the template name is template2 after the first update). So it looks like the `templateForm` is not getting updated when I click save even though I run the `loadTemplates` method which should rebuild the FormGroup, but rather the keys are still set to the previous template names which were there when I first loaded the page. How can I make sure that the FormGroup gets updated when the values in the form are updated?

Comment: it seems it would be easier with ` templateForm`  as a ` FormArray`  of templateName ` FormControl`

Comment: It's looks like you call a function with an argument (that is an object) and change it in this function (I can see this in your code). BTW. You're creating a formGroup of formGroups with an unique FormControl (I don't know if it's because you are simplify the question) perhafs you need rethinking the formGroup